# What's wrong with this Perl boolean syntax?

Tags: perl, syntax, operator-precedence

I have hack I need to employ under these conditions:

- It's the last page of data.
- It's not the first page, either.
- There's not a page-size-even number of data items.

So I tried this code:

```
my $use_hack = 
   $last_page_number == $current_page_number and
   $page_number != 1 and
   $total_items % $items_per_page != 0;
```

And I keep getting this warning `Useless use of numeric ne (!=) in void context` about the last condition and it's evaluating true when `$total_items % $items_per_page = 0`.

```
say 'NOT EVEN' if $total_items % $items_per_page != 0;  #works properly, though...
```

I've tried various combinations of parentheses to get it right, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: FYI, you can use this to see how Perl is parsing a piece of code: `perl -MO=Deparse some_program.pl`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Okay, operator precedence. `and` has almost the lowest precedence of any operator in Perl, so Perl was evaluating the expression in a weird order.  Switching to `&&` instead got me correct results. Blarg.

[The More You Know](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity).

EDIT:
As Philip Potter pointed out below, *Perl Best Practices* (p.70) recommends always using `&&,||, !` for boolean conditions - limiting `and or` and `not` for control flow because of their low precedence.  (And it even goes so far as to say to never use `and` and `not`, only `or` for fallback logic.)
Thanks, everybody!

Comment: Use `and`/`or` for `my $foo = blarg() or die 'blarg is broke';`  Use `&&`/`||` for `my $foo = blarg() || 'default value';`  Always consider precedence: `$foo = $a and blarg()` is very different than `$bar = $b && blarg();`

Answer (score 7):

Enclose the RHS in parenthesis:

```
my $use_hack = (
   $last_page_number == $current_page_number and
   $page_number != 1 and
   $total_items % $items_per_page != 0);
```

Assignment (`=`) is having higher precedence when compared to `and` operator. You can take a look at the [Perl Operator Precedence](http://www.perl.com/doc/manual/html/pod/perlop.html).

Comment: Simultaneous discovery!  So the next question is 'Which is better?'

Comment: @wes: I prefer to use `&&`, `||`, and `!` only for calculating boolean expressions, `or` only for flow control (particularly `or die` or `or croak`). I never use `and` or `not`. This almost always results in the precedence you want, and when you want different order of evaluation, you can use parens to show that you really meant what you say. See also Perl Best Pracices, p70.